# Add new object value for AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Unlike the GET, POST of AJAX has diff data, like this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data : {data: true},
url: '...'

});
```

How can I add new object to the data?

I thought of do like this

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : ajaxVar,
    url: '...'

    });

ajaxVar = {data : true};
//add new object to ajaxVar
```

But I stuck here. I can do {data: true, dataExtra: 'like this'} but I have an if. Eg.

```
if(function()){
// add new object to ajaxVar
}
```

I do not want to add extra code so I want to add new object to existing ajaxVar.

Answer (score 2):

a property need to be added to the data-object before ajax-request. you can use a dot or array access to add a new property:

```
ajaxVar.newProp = newVal;
```

or

```
ajaxVar["newProp"] = newVal;
```

and all together:

```
//declaration
var ajaxVal = {};

// some conditional asignment work
if( somethingIsTrue() ){
    ajaxVar.newProp = newVal;
}

// ajax request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data : ajaxVar,
    url: '...'
});
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, a single line is fine, but it is needed. I've arrived here from a moderation queue because this was automatically flagged. Keeping answers to high quality will help prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data : {var1: value1, var2: value2, var3: value3},
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a synchronous language meaning code will get executed in the order that it is written. If you would like to have send data in an Ajax request, set the data above the Ajax code and all should be well.

Example:

```
var data = {}
if (isTrue()) {
    data.property = true;
}

$.ajax({
    data: data,
    ...
});
```